# when using mvn jetty:run, which version of jetty it is running?

Tags: servlets, maven-2, jetty

when I use mvn jetty:run, how do I know which version of jetty it is using?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it displayed on the console?

```
2012-03-05 14:50:39.204:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.1.v20120215
```

If you can't see that, try mvn with `-X`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically it is not a good idea to leave that version up to the powers that be.  Better to declare the version of jetty you use to use, which is a one to one correlation between the version of the plugin and the version of jetty as we release them at the same time.